# how to draw horizontal lines and show price tag for each line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have my own calculation method to calculate some pressure and support prices, and I want to draw the horizontal lines of these pressure and support prices, as well as showing the price for each line. Below is what i want(it is tradingview built-in Fibonacci retracement lines):
[image: what I want is showing lines with price tags for each line]

and my own code is like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="testing-pressure and support", overlay=true)

//中心价和 K 线振幅
float mid_price = (high + low) / 2
float diff      = high - low 

//support price
float support1  = mid_price - 0.618 * diff
float support2  = mid_price - 1 * diff

//压力位
float pressure1 = mid_price + 0.618 * diff
float pressure2 = mid_price + 1 * diff

//是否显示支撑位和压力位
show_support = input.bool(title="显示支撑位", defval=true) 
show_pressure = input.bool(title="显示压力位", defval=true) 
show_mid_price = input.bool(title="显示中心价", defval=true) 

//绘制支撑位和压力位
line_length = input.int(defval=10, title="支撑/压力线的长度")

if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index-1, support1[1], bar_index+line_length,support1[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    line.new(bar_index-1, support2[1], bar_index+line_length,support2[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, pressure1[1], bar_index+line_length,pressure1[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    line.new(bar_index-1, pressure2[1], bar_index+line_length,pressure2[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, mid_price[1], bar_index+line_length, mid_price[1], color = show_mid_price ? color.yellow : na, width = 1)
```

The code works like below:
[image: display result of my own code]

The lines are drawn and displayed successfully but I don't know how to put a price tag for each line like the above mentioned picture showing. So can you help me on this?

Apart from above question, I also have another demand：let me select a bar's low point to another bar's high point, it will be a period which includes maybe 5 bars or 8 bars or 20 bars... in this period, there is also high/low/open/close. I want to draw some lines base on the period high/period low/period open/period close. How to achieve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added numbers to be on top of your lines:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Testing", overlay=true)

//中心价和 K 线振幅
float mid_price = (high + low) / 2
float diff      = high - low 

//support price
float support1  = mid_price - 0.618 * diff
float support2  = mid_price - 1 * diff

//压力位
float pressure1 = mid_price + 0.618 * diff
float pressure2 = mid_price + 1 * diff

//是否显示支撑位和压力位
show_support = input.bool(title="显示支撑位", defval=true) 
show_pressure = input.bool(title="显示压力位", defval=true) 
show_mid_price = input.bool(title="显示中心价", defval=true)

//绘制支撑位和压力位
line_length = input.int(defval=10, title="支撑/压力线的长度")

if barstate.islast
    if show_support
        line.new(bar_index-1, support1[1], bar_index+line_length, support1[1], color=color.green, width=1)
        label.new(bar_index+line_length, support1[1], text=str.tostring(support1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)

        line.new(bar_index-1, support2[1], bar_index+line_length, support2[1], color=color.green, width=1)
        label.new(bar_index+line_length, support2[1], text=str.tostring(support2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)

    if show_pressure
        line.new(bar_index-1, pressure1[1], bar_index+line_length, pressure1[1], color=color.red, width=1)
        label.new(bar_index+line_length, pressure1[1], text=str.tostring(pressure1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.red, textcolor=color.red, size=size.small)

        line.new(bar_index-1, pressure2[1], bar_index+line_length, pressure2[1], color=color.red, width=1)
        label.new(bar_index+line_length, pressure2[1], text=str.tostring(pressure2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.red, textcolor=color.red, size=size.small)
    
    if show_mid_price
        line.new(bar_index-1, mid_price[1], bar_index+line_length, mid_price[1], color=color.yellow, width=1)
        label.new(bar_index+line_length, mid_price[1], text=str.tostring(mid_price[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.yellow, size=size.small)
```

Which produces:

[image]

If you wish, you can add different styles of labels to the lines.

As for drawing lines between the high and low (and other points), I put this in your last question - will it not suffice? You could apply the logic to draw lines between any two points:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Testing", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast and bar_index >= 3
    line.new(bar_index - 4, high[4], bar_index, low, width=1, color=color.blue)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Now I have one more problem: I want to calculate the support and pressure lines based on the timeframe of "1D", and then no matter I switch the bar chart to any timeframe, it always shows the support and pressure of "1D". I post my code(which does't work properly) in below my own answer, can you help me check? Thank you.

Comment: hey bro, I already asked another question for "how to show the lines which is calculated on a fixed timeframe and it will not change when  I switch the chart timeframe". Please go through it whenever u r free. Thank you.